# What should be my approach for angularjs nested ajax calls [loop within a loop]?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
|        |     |            |  A1  |            |     |                   |
| AJAX 1 | --> |  Response1 |  --> |   AJAX 2   | --> | Response2 (Final) |
|        |     | [ARRAY]-A1 |      | A1 indices |     |                   |
```

So, the problem is that I've to show Response2 in my DOM but AJAX 2 is dependent on Response1. What would be the best approach for such a scenario?
I'm trying to do it with deferred promises in UI Router resolve object but it seems that the resolve is not being executed in config.

**What I want to achieve -** 
I'm getting an array (Array 1) from AJAX1 as response. I want to run AJAX calls on each of the elements of that Array 1 and store the response from each of these calls in another array(Array 2). Finally return that Array 2 so as to be displayed in the DOM.

**EDITED** (Updated with code)

```
myApp.factory('Factory1',function($q, $rootScope){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var tempFactory = {};
   tempFactory.function1 = function(){
      (GAPI AJAX CALL)
      .execute(function(response){
         $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            var res = response.KEY1;  //Array
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return res;
         });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
   };
   return tempFactory;
}

myApp.factory('Factory2',function($q, $rootScope, res){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var tempFactory = {};
   tempFactory.function2 = function(res){
      (GAPI AJAX CALL)    //res as an argument
      .execute(function(response){
         var resultLength = res.length;
         $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            for (i=0; i <res.length; i++){
               resultLength -= 1;
               var result = [];
               result.push(response.KEY2[i]);
               if (resultLength <= 1){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
                  return result;
               }
            }
         });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
   };
   return tempFactory;
}

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
       .state('state1',{
       url: '/state',
       templateUrl:'partials/user.html',
       resolve: {
           videos: function(Factory1, Factory2){
               console.log('hi there');
               return Factory1.function1()
               .then(Factory2.function2);
           }
       },
       controller:'Controller1',
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Could you show the code of what you've tried?

Comment: Added. I hope it's much clearer now.

Comment: What is the real problem? Is there any exception thrown? Or it just that the result is somehow incorrect?

Comment: No error in the console.

Comment: Then please elaborate more on what exactly is the `it's breaking somewhere`. Also what you are expecting and the actual result of the current implementation. I could't help without knowing what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Sure. Added the 'What I want to achieve' in the question and It's there in the primitive graphical representation at the top too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through and fire an AJAX call for each element of the result of the first AJAX call.
Then wait for all the calls to complete by counting.

I assume your data is in `response.KEY1` and `response.KEY2`.

```
myApp.factory('Factory1', function($q, $rootScope) {
  var tempFactory = {};

  tempFactory.function1 = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    (GAPI AJAX CALL)
    .execute(function(response) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        deferred.resolve(response.KEY1);
      });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return tempFactory;
});

myApp.factory('Factory2', function($q, $rootScope) {
  var tempFactory = {};

  tempFactory.function2 = function(res) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result = [];
    var count = 0;

    angular.forEach(res, function (r, i) {
      (GAPI AJAX CALL) // r as an argument
      .execute(function (response) {
        result[i] = response.KEY2;

        count++;
        if (count === res.length) {
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            deferred.resolve(result);
          });
        }
      });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return tempFactory;
});
```

Hope this helps.